# reshape 2d numpy array with most frequent elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I would like to reshape 2d numpy arrays to smaller shapes and populate it with the most frequent elements within a specified block.

For example to go from a shape (4,4) to (2,2) I can use reshape and max to get the maximum values:

```
x = numpy. array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
                  [3, 2, 5, 4],
                  [3, 6, 5, 2],
                  [1, 1, 5, 1]])

shape = (2, 2, 2, 2)

x.reshape(shape).max(-1).max(1)
```

Which will give a shape (2,2) with the maximum values for each block of (2,2):

```
[[3 5]
 [6 5]]
```

But is there a way to get a similar array with the most frequent values for each block of 4?
The outcome should then be:

```
[[1 2]
 [1 5]]
```

Comment: How would you get all the 4 blocks `[[1,1],[3,2]]` , `[[2,2],[5,4]]`,.. etc?

Answer (score 0):

**You can get all the blocks you need using list comprehension**:

```
x = [[1, 1, 2, 2],
     [3, 2, 5, 4],
     [3, 6, 5, 2],
     [1, 1, 5, 1]]

top_left = [a[:2] for a in x[:2]]
#[[1, 1], [3, 2]]

top_right = [a[2:] for a in x[:2]]
#[[2, 2], [5, 4]]

bottom_left = [a[:2] for a in x[2:4]]
#[[3, 6], [1, 1]]

bottom_right = [a[2:] for a in x[2:4]]
#[[5, 2], [5, 1]]
```

**Flatten these blocks and get the mode**:

```
from statistics import mode

mode([item for sublist in top_left for item in sublist])
#1

mode([item for sublist in top_right for item in sublist])
#2

mode([item for sublist in bottom_left for item in sublist])
#1

mode([item for sublist in bottom_right for item in sublist])
#5
```